# Testing with react-beautiful-dnd and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, react-beautiful-dnd

I just started using react-beautiful-dnd and implemented my first drag and drop, by adapting some React components I already had.

The problem I'm facing is that, given r-b-dnd's usage, children of `Droppable` and `Draggable` components need to be wrapped in functions to fit library usage, such as, in my simple use case:

```js
<DragDropContext
onDragEnd={this.onCardDragEnd}
>
  <Droppable droppableId={"my-cards-column"}>
      {(provided: DroppableProvided) => (
          <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
              {myCards}
              {provided.placeholder}
          </div>
      )}
  </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```

Before integrating this library, I had a lot of working unit tests using Jest + Enzyme's shallow wrapping, that way I could test behaviors of my list such as "a card has been added", "a card has been deleted", and so on.

Of course, now that my children components (cards) are wrapped in this r-b-dnd function, I'm having a really hard-time trying to fix the tests which are now broken, because I can't use Enzyme's `dive` and `find` to work my way down my shallow wrapper anymore. The reason is simple: they are not rendered in my tests anymore, so I cannot reach them to make assertions.

As I've seen, there is no official way of testing components which are using r-b-dnd: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/623

This thread has been opened since 2018 and we can't expect any support or reactions on issues in this repository anymore, as stated in the README.

I'm not even trying to test the lib itself here, but I would at least need to fix my previous tests and make them coexist with r-b-dnd somehow.
If I'm losing testing capabilities and/or coverage due to the integration of a new lib, I'm afraid I won't be able to keep it in my app and will have to find another one to use.

How should I go about this? Any tips or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: it is possible but trust me it is a PAIN. In tests you arent expected to test imported libraries, they should be tested themselves. If you are able to use mocks, just mock react-rnd with some buttons that trigger the functionality you need to test.

Comment: I ended up doing something along those lines:
1) converting my unit tests to integration tests (using react-testing-library) and mocking react-beautiful-dnd so that my tests behave as if the lib wasn't there at all
2) testing my drag and drop callbacks by writing unit tests for different use cases.
It's not optimal, but at least it covers all the previous and new test cases, which is enough for me.
If someone reading this needs help with this approach, please respond and I'll elaborate by writing an "answer" to my question, even if it's far from perfect